# Convert the equation into an equivalent system of first order differential equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y'''(t)+sin(t)y''(t)-g(t)y'(t)+g(t)y(t) = f(t)$$

Write the following third order differential equation as an equivalent system of first order ordinary differential equations and write it in the form

$$\frac{dz}{dt} = f(t,z)$$

Here is what I have so far:
$$x_1(t)=y(t)$$
$$x_2(t)=y'(t)$$
$$x_3(t)=y''(t)$$

so I can then do,
$$x_1'(t)=y'(t)$$
$$x_2'(t)=y''(t)$$
$$x_3'(t)=y'''(t) = f(t)-sin(t)y''(t)+g(t)y'(t)-g(t)y(t)$$
$$x_3'(t)=f(t)-sin(t)x_3(t)+g(t)x_2(t)-g(t)x_1(t)$$

and I think the dynamics function is:

$$f(t,z) = [x_1'(t), x_2''(t), x_3'''(t)]$$

$$f(t,z) = [x_2(t), x_3(t), f(t)-sin(t)x_3(t)+g(t)x_2(t)-g(t)x_1(t)]$$

I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly. What does difference does the f(t) and g(t) make in this case? what is z exactly?

I'd really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that your final goal is to obtain a system of FIRST order equations. So, any higher derivatives need to be rewritten appropriately.

Using your notation, we have

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
x_1'&=&x_2\\
x_2'&=&x_3\\
x_3'&=&f(t)-\sin(t)x_3+g(t)x_2-g(t)x_1
\end{array}
$$

Here $z$ would represent the $3$-vector $\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3 \end{pmatrix}$.

Try and think of the entire set of expressions on the right hand side as the output of multivariable function from $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$. (It's not the best idea to use $f$ again in this context. Think of $f(t,z)$ as $f(t,x_1,x_2,x_3)$.

Comment: so the vector z is input to f(t, z) which is that system of equations?

Comment: I'm assuming so. Usually there is a difference in the way vectors are written, (boldface, or other notation such as an arrow). Is there any such indication in your question?

Comment: the z is bolder

Comment: The next part gives me some initial values, as well as g(t)=1 and f(t)=1 and asks me to solve 2 steps with the forward Euler method. Does having the f(t) and g(t) make some difference that I'm not noticing, or would they just go away?

Comment: Replace $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ with $1$ and carry out the Euler method. Be very careful with translating initial values into initial values for your new variables.

Comment: it told me that the initial value is t=0 and a the vector(1,1,1). I think that is referencing z already, so I don't need to translate the values.